# Does oracle provide a built-in currency table for me to use as constraints?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, constraints

I'm creating a table in Oracle 11g like this:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE (
    ID VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR2(100), 
    SHORT VARCHAR2(50),
    CURRENCY CHAR(3)
);
```

Is it possible to create a **foreign key constraint** or even a **check constraint** on `CURRENCY` to a built-in Oracle table that contains the [ISO currencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)?

Not having a great understanding of databases I also take as input other solutions that might be out there, however I do not want to maintain my own table for this, if it's too much work, I'll live with user errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Edited to include @A.B.Cade's suggestion.

Unfortunately you can't directly add a constraint, as the currencies data is available through a system a view. You can, however, create your own table with that information and then create the foreign key. Here's an example of how you can do it.

```
CREATE TABLE currencies (
  country VARCHAR2(30) PRIMARY KEY,
  currency VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO currencies
  SELECT value country, utl_i18n.get_default_iso_currency(value) currency
    FROM v$nls_valid_values
   WHERE parameter = 'TERRITORY';

CREATE INDEX currencies_iso_idx ON currencies(currency) COMPUTE STATISTICS;

ALTER TABLE example ADD CONSTRAINT example_currency_fk FOREIGN KEY (currency)
  REFERENCES currencies(currency);
```

The example above includes an index on the currency value, as I suspect that will what you'll be querying on.

Comment: Actually Oracle does support currencies, see example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/27400

Comment: I will reword, I mean having a list of currencies available. Thank you.

Comment: yep, thanks @A.B.Cade! I think this is a good question/answer for users wanting the same thing. thanks both.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of ISO currencies from a built in view in oracle:

```
select utl_i18n.GET_DEFAULT_ISO_CURRENCY(value) iso_cur
from v$nls_valid_values
where parameter = 'TERRITORY'
```

But as Nuno Guerreiro said, you'll need to create a table from these results and add a foreign key to the new table.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't understand what do you mean by "default Oracle table that contains ISO currencies" (do you mean Oracle PeopleSoft CURRENCY_CD_TBL table?), but in general you can alter your table after creation to add foreign key constraint.
Here is an example:

```
    ALTER TABLE EXAMPLE
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_currency
      FOREIGN KEY (CURRENCY)
      REFERENCES put_parent_table_name_here(_corresponding_field_name_in_perent_table);
```

You also can add constraint definition into CREATE TABLE statement.
Here is an example:

```
    CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE (
        ID VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY,
        NAME VARCHAR2(100), 
        SHORT VARCHAR2(50),
        CURRENCY CHAR(3),
      CONSTRAINT fk_currency
      FOREIGN KEY (CURRENCY)
      REFERENCES put_parent_table_name_here(_corresponding_field_name_in_perent_table)
    );
```

Comment: by default oracle table I mean a table that ships with Oracle, not one I would create myself. I will edit to built-in. is that more clear?

Comment: your comment is helpful to know how to add the constrain. Yes, I want to do that, but the table I'm linking to is my main point.

Comment: There is no such table in clean Oracle Database installation. Oracle provide it with some products like PeopleSoft. If you use something like that - check its documentation, or give us some additional info about which Oracle product do you mean

Comment: standard oracle 11g, no add-ons. I think you've replied with your last comment, that is inline with @nmdguerreiro answer as well.