# How to create a table in Oracle 11g with the list of language codes based on util_i18n?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, internationalization

The other day I asked how to generate a list of currencies based on a built-in oracle table if possible: [Does oracle provide a built-in currency table for me to use as constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808897/does-oracle-provide-a-built-in-currency-table-for-me-to-use-as-constraints/22809478?noredirect=1#comment34785472_22809478).

Now I need a list of the language codes, so I went to read the documentation for [util_i18n](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_i18n.htm#CACEAJFA) and I found a function named `GET_LOCAL_LANGUAGES`. I tried to adapt the script from the previous answer to this new problem but failed. This is mainly because my oracle/sql knowlegde is terrible:

The original I'm trying to adapt from:

```
select utl_i18n.GET_DEFAULT_ISO_CURRENCY(value) iso_cur
from v$nls_valid_values
where parameter = 'TERRITORY'
```

My attempt to use it for the languages:

```
select utl_i18n.GET_LOCAL_LANGUAGES(value) lang_cur
from v$nls_valid_values
where parameter = 'TERRITORY'
```

I checked the docs and `TERRITORY` is the parameter name as well, that part was not a guess. With this query I get error: `invalid data type`

I bet this is a noob question, but all my tries have failed so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pipelined wrapper for example (original function returns package-defined collection type):

```
SQL> create type t_lang_tab is table of varchar2(4000)
  2  /

SQL> create or replace function get_language(
  2   p_value in varchar2
  3  ) return t_lang_tab
  4  pipelined
  5  is
  6    res utl_i18n.string_array;
  7  begin
  8    res := utl_i18n.GET_LOCAL_LANGUAGES(p_value);
  9    if res is not null then
 10      for i in 1..res.count loop
 11        pipe row (substr(res(i),1,4000));
 12      end loop;
 13    end if;
 14    return;
 15  end;
 16  /

SQL> col column_value format a25
SQL> col value format a25
SQL> select t.column_value, p.value
  2  from v$nls_valid_values p,
  3  table(get_language(p.value)) t
  4  where parameter = 'TERRITORY'
  5  /

COLUMN_VALUE              VALUE                                                 
------------------------- -------------------------                             
ENGLISH                   AMERICA                                               
GERMAN DIN                GERMANY                                               
CANADIAN FRENCH           CANADA                                                
FRENCH                    CANADA                                                
CATALAN                   SPAIN                                                 
SWEDISH                   FINLAND                                               
PORTUGUESE                BRAZIL                                                
LATIN AMERICAN SPANISH    MEXICO                                                
SPANISH                   MEXICO                                                
SPANISH                   CATALONIA                                             
ARABIC                    EGYPT   
....
```

If you want to create language table you can do this:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE languages (
  2    country VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  3    language VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  4    CONSTRAINT languages_pk PRIMARY KEY (country, language)
  5  )
  6  /
```

Primary key should be composite because there are multi-lingual countries like Canada.
Now you can use above function to fill table:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO languages
  2  select p.value, t.column_value
  3  from v$nls_valid_values p,
  4  table(get_language(p.value)) t
  5  where parameter = 'TERRITORY'
  6  order by 1
  7  /

SQL> commit;

SQL> select * from languages;

COUNTRY                        LANGUAGE                                         
------------------------------ ------------------------------                   
AMERICA                        ENGLISH                                          
ARGENTINA                      SPANISH                                          
BELARUS                        RUSSIAN                                          
BELGIUM                        FRENCH                                           
BRAZIL                         PORTUGUESE                                       
CANADA                         FRENCH                                           
CANADA                         CANADIAN FRENCH                                  
CATALONIA                      SPANISH                                          
CHILE                          SPANISH                                          
COLOMBIA                       SPANISH    
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dmitry. I would prefer to use the example above. You provided a very good answer, but can you tell me how to follow the same pattern as before. I would like to create my table like I did for the currencies, I'm such a gigantic sql noob that I'm missing something basic. I read your select on the bottom but I can't use it in isolation.

Comment: I added few scripts to you. Hope this helps.